# Dataframe operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe populated with different zeros and values different than zero. For each row I want to apply the following condition:

If the value in the given cell is different than zero AND the value in the cell to the right is zero, then put the same value in the cell to the right.

The example would be the following:

This is the one of the rows in the dataframe now:

```
[0,0,0,20,0,0,0,33,3,0,5,0,0,0,0,0]
```

The function would convert it to the following:

```
[0,0,0,20,20,20,20,33,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,5]
```

I want to apply this to the whole dataframe.

Your help would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Where exactly are you stuck codewise?

Answer (score 0):

Since you imply you are using Pandas, I would leverage a bit of the build-in muscle in the library.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([0,0,0,20,0,0,0,33,3,0,5,0,0,0,0,0])
s.replace(0, np.NaN, inplace=True)
s = s.ffill()
```

Output:

```
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3     20.0
4     20.0
5     20.0
6     20.0
7     33.0
8      3.0
9      3.0
10     5.0
11     5.0
12     5.0
13     5.0
14     5.0
15     5.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: How do I apply this logic to the full dataframe? I have to make these changes in every row

Comment: If your DataFrame is a mere container for data series - as defined in the question, yes, you would have to apply this logic sequentially over ether rows or columns, depending on how the DataFrame is structured.